# how to make Links to dynamic content working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dynamic

I have a application written in php/js. And application has some dynamic links which needs to be working directly .

E.g.:
I want example.com/#/link1 to be accesible from outside my website. For example. I would like to post the example.com/#/link1 link in facebook.com so my friends can see it. However, when someone clicks on the link, it will take him to example.com/#link1, NOT example.com/ . How can i do it ?

Comment: the link you posted is relative to a very specific button of your web application? if yes you need to process that link on the onload of your js

Comment: If you are using a framework like backbonejs, the router takes care to render the right part of your application (http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-router/). Also other JS frameworks like EmberJS have that functionality. If you don't use such a framework, you have to take care of changing urls and rendering the views on your own. (you can also skip the # by using HTML5 pushstate (http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html)

Comment: i am not using any framework..can any1 provide me the code snippet ..how to do tthis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/balupton/jquery-history this might solve your problem